# How to grab sheet ID from URLs with different formats using ARRAYFORMULA(Regexextract) in googlesheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using REGEXEXTRACT with array formula to grab sheet ID from URLs.
The most common format URLs appearing in my sheet is

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx/edit#gid=1029712659
```

for which I'm using

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT (D2:D,".*/(.*)/"))
```

but for certain URLs the format is

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/xxxxx
```

for which i can use `REGEXEXTRACT (D15,".*/(.*)")` separate but when I do that the whole column values disappear and only the designated cell is showing value.

Is there a way I can do both the things in the arrayformula itself?

I have attached screen shots below

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Note after the `.` there is star symbol present in expression.
I don't know why it's not reflecting.

Comment: your formulas don't seem to work separarely either.... Also the **sheet** id is this part `1029712659`. The `xxx...` is the **spreadsheet** id. And in the `folder` url you have a **folder** id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(.*)d\/|\/edit.*",""))
```

OR even

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B,"(.+)d\/|\/.+",""))
```

[image]

*(do adjust ranges and locale syntax to meet your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D, "folder"), REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D,".*/(.*)"), REGEXEXTRACT(D2:D,".*/(.*)/"))))
```

**Example:**

[image]